# Matillion API profile configure to post request

Tags: matillion

I'm totally new to Matillion and I'm not sure how to manage Matillion API profile for POST request.

I have an orchestration and transformation job which extracts data from source and does the business logic through transform and load the data into target table.

Once the data has been loaded into target table(Snowflake DB) from which I need to extract the data and make API POST call for data ingestion in JSON format to third party vendor.

```
Sample command line argument to make API post call using curl

curl -L https://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/v1/load_data -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -H 'x-api-key: somekey'  -d '{"is_ingestion_finished": false, "job_id": "", "chunk_number": 1, "payload": [{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"},{"key1": "value1_1","key2": "value2_2"}]'
```

Above command line argument will ingest the data through POST. Please note that "is_ingestion_finished" value need to be set false until the last chunk of data is retrieved from target table and at the last chunk it should be set as true. For the first chunk the "job_id" should be set as null. Once the first chunk has been processed we will be getting the job id in API response and that needs to be used for rest of the chunks.

I have gone through Matillion docs and it seems like API Query component is used to make GET requests through API and store it in table.

Not sure on how to post the data from target table by making API post request,  Also I'll be needing pagination logic to post request as the data set is huge and result set needs to be sent in chunks.

Matillion version which I'm currently using is 1.46.5(build 2). Any help with steps to configure the API profile or any sample rsd script or python scripts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

1. define a job variable to contain the payload that is in the snowflake table
2. use 'query result to scalar' component to load the payload from snowflake into the variable
3. Use the 'Python script' component (orchestration job: scripting) to do the POST event in Matillion.

There is also a new component in Matillion: "Webhook Post" that may do what you are looking for as well: https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2576584